# On Azure portal I see some error in graph HTTP 5xx but I am unable to see detail of it on linux app service .net core 2.2

Tags: azure, 500-error, azure-app-services

I am using azure Linux app service for my `.NET core 2.2` . I see error in graph but unable to find to error detail its really important for me. I have checked also for the folder of logs ['Explained Here'](https://serverfault.com/questions/949418/monitoring-http-5xx-errors-in-an-azure-app-service) but did not found any where I can see my error logs output of it . Any quick and easy solution where I can find logs ?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried the "diagnose issues" feature in the portal? This should show you errors.

Comment: in diagnose issue it only show sql server not my hosting server

Comment: Hey, what did you discover in this? I'm facing a similar issue where I can see the spikes in the 5xx graph but there are no errors in the logs.